# Как коммиту добавить родителя?

Tags: git

Подскажите возможно ли такое что коммит не имеет родителя и если да , то как к нему добавить родителя

Comment: Да, самый первый коммит всегда без родителя. Зачем вам добавлять родителя?

Answer (score 1):

1. самый первый в хранилище коммит, по понятным причинам, не имеет ни одного родителя.
2. коммит, у которого в качестве родительских указано более одного коммита, называется коммитом слияния (*merge commit*). создаётся он командой `merge`:

   ```
   $ git merge [опции] указатель2 указатель3 ...
   ```

   нумерация указана начиная с двойки намеренно — первым родительским коммитом является тот, на который указывает динамический указатель `HEAD` (у «обычных» коммитов он и является единственным родительским).
3. технически возможно внести в (уже имеющее коммиты) хранилище ещё один (и более) коммит без «родителя», но делать этого не стоит, даже если программа *git* и справится с такой **нештатной** ситуацией.
4. штатных средств добавить/удалить «родителя» у существующего коммита — нет. хотя технически это, конечно, и возможно, и бессмысленно.

Comment: 3. "делать этого не стоит" - почему же?

Comment: 3. "с такой нештатной ситуацией" - с какой стати она нештатная, если есть более одного штатного способа это сделать?

Comment: 4. "бессмысленно" - нет. Это может иметь смысл, например, при миграции проекта в git. Если у нас сначала оказалось просто последнее состояние, и мы его начали править, а потом уже решили влить историю из предыдущей СКВ/архивов

Answer (score 0):

> Подскажите возможно ли такое что коммит не имеет родителя

Да. У первого коммита нет родителя. Учитывая, что у merge-коммитов более одного родителя, может быть несколько "первых" коммитов.

> как к нему добавить родителя

Единственный способ это сделать - сначала создать тот коммит, который будет родительским, а потом выполнить rebase на него.